# Why is the call() function not working with an object created with an already created class

Tags: javascript, object

I am a javaScript beginner. I was trying to run a call function to an object which I created using a class. I expected an output - "Virat Kohli" with the following code :

```
    class person {
constructor(firstName,lastName){
    firstName = this.firstName;
    lastName = this.lastName
}
}


perFullName = {
    fullName : function(){
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}

const vk = new person("Virat","Kohli");
console.log(perFullName.fullName.call(vk))
```

But this returned me `undefined undefined` in my VS code console, but when I replaced it and created the object like this :

```
const vk = {
    firstName : "Virat",
    lastName : "Kohli"
}
```

It returned the expected output.

Can you please tell me the reason and how I can fix it?

Comment: You switched the assignment target and the value to assign. `firstName = this.firstName;` should be `this.firstName = firstName;`. You want to assign the value of `firstName` to the object's `firstName` property (`this.firstName`), not the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable assignments in the constructor are back-to-front, they should assign the input values to the member variables.

Your `fullName` function can be moved into the class as a read only property getter:

```js
class person {
    constructor(firstName, lastName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName
    }
    
    get fullName() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}

const vk = new person("Virat", "Kohli");
console.log(vk.fullName);
```